# I cannot access a MySQL container using a hostname, but I can with it's IP address

Tags: mysql, dns, docker

I just setup [dnsdock](https://github.com/tonistiigi/dnsdock) at my development machine to be able to resolve containers hostnames to it's real IP addresses.

Apache containers are working fine, I can use http://www.miraflores.dev to access web pages, but **I cannot connect to MySQL containers from the host machine using its hostnames**, only if I use their IP addresses:

```
$ mysql -h sql.miraflores.dev -u root -proot
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'sql.miraflores.dev' (0)

$ ping sql.miraflores.dev
PING sql.miraflores.dev (172.17.42.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from miraflores.dev (172.17.42.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms

$ mysql -h 172.17.42.3 -u root -proot
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.5.46 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
mysql>
```

It's very strange.

Comment: Can you do `dig @172.17.42.1 sql.miraflores.dev` and confirm there is only one record?

Comment: `; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.7-Ubuntu <<>> @172.17.42.1 sql.miraflores.dev
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30846
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;sql.miraflores.dev.  IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
sql.miraflores.dev. 0 IN A 172.17.42.3

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 172.17.42.1#53(172.17.42.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 25 10:53:43 CET 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 70`